# Choose between python "conda root" and python "default" instead of Python "3" in Jupyter

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I have the latest version of anaconda on Redhat 6.7 . I have a pre-installed version of Python "Python 3.6". When I launch Jupyter and I would to create a new Notebook, it suggests for me to choose between [conda root] and python [default ] instead of Python [3] .

I follow this tuto to resolve the probleme: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1805#issuecomment-251237272

when i was trying to launch a new Python [3] instance, i got a 404 page, this is the console output:

```
[W 17:58:34.775 NotebookApp] 404 GET /undefined (10.156.46.147) 2.62ms referer=None
[I 17:58:34.800 NotebookApp] Creating new notebook in
[I 17:58:36.198 NotebookApp] Kernel started: efbaa214-e4a7-4a41-bf10-392e3afd78e9
```

Can someone please help me to understand the issue and explain what is wrong with my case?